# Upgrading Project with Template 10 V1.1.0 to v1.1.12

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I've updated Template 10 in a previously working, but unpublished T10 UWP application from version 1.1.0 to 1.1.12. The project uses MvvmLight and PropertyChanged.Fody too.

I've corrected `OnNavigatedTo` to `OnNavigatedToAsync` in ViewModels.

To App.Xaml.cs I added

```
// jha from 1.1.12
AutoSuspendAllFrames = true;
AutoRestoreAfterTerminated = true;
AutoExtendExecutionSession = true;
```

The program starts displaying the Splash screen then I get a Just-In-Time unhandled win32 exception error that I haven't learned how to get past to drill down further in debugging.

**Update: 1/19/2017** Found the debugger setting; Debugger Type->Application process 'Mixed' set in Project->Properties->Debug->Debugger Type

Still the specific line of code is not identified. I get the following

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x055E4201 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Decisive.exe:
 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred
 (parameters:0x0E98B408, 0x00000002). occurred
```

I don't see where I can copy the Call Stack to include here.

**End Update**

[image]

In the debug log near the end, note the SerializationException(s) after `06:20:18.8929626 Template10 NavigationService.NavigateToAsync Mode: New, Parameter:  FrameContent: Decisive.Uwp.T10.Views.MainPage` before `06:20:19.1159643 Template10 HamburgerMenu.HamburgerMenu_Loaded`

Debug Log

```
06:20:17.6669634 Template10 BootStrapper.OnWindowCreated 
06:20:17.6764639 Template10 WindowWrapper.Static Constructor 
06:20:17.6819619 Template10 BootStrapper.Loaded 
06:20:17.6969638 Template10 DispatcherWrapper.Constructor 
06:20:17.7054654 Template10 BootStrapper.OnLaunched 
06:20:17.7119639 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to BeforeLaunch
06:20:17.7304645 Template10 BootStrapper.InternalLaunchAsync Previous:NotRunning
06:20:17.7364642 Template10 BootStrapper.InitializeFrameAsync IActivatedEventArgs:Launch
06:20:17.7394649 Template10 BootStrapper.CallShowSplashScreen 
06:20:17.8369630 Template10 BootStrapper.ActivateWindow source:SplashScreen
06:20:17.8409634 Template10 BootStrapper.CallOnInitializeAsync 
06:20:17.8454679 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to BeforeInit
06:20:17.8519624 Template10 BootStrapper.NavigationServiceFactory backButton:Attach ExistingContent:Include
06:20:17.8574621 Template10 BootStrapper.NavigationServiceFactory backButton:Attach existingContent:Include frame:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame
06:20:17.8639639 Template10 BootStrapper.CreateNavigationService Frame:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame
06:20:18.0419627 Template10 HamburgerMenu..ctor 
06:20:18.0509643 Template10 HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons OldValue:  NewValue: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Template10.Controls.HamburgerButtonInfo]
06:20:18.0534637 Template10 HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons OldValue:  NewValue: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Template10.Controls.HamburgerButtonInfo]
06:20:18.1034623 Template10 HamburgerMenu.AccentColor OldValue: #00000000 NewValue: #FF4682B4
06:20:18.1084624 Template10 HamburgerMenu.RefreshStyles Color: #FF4682B4
06:20:18.1139641 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavAreaBackground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1229646 Template10 HamburgerMenu.SecondarySeparator OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1274629 Template10 HamburgerMenu.PaneBorderBrush OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1329635 Template10 HamburgerMenu.PaneBorderThickness OldValue: 0,0,1,0 NewValue: 0,0,0,0
06:20:18.1364626 Template10 HamburgerMenu.HamburgerForeground OldValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1394637 Template10 HamburgerMenu.HamburgerBackground OldValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1429640 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonForeground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1469635 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonBackground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1499630 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonCheckedForeground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1534642 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonCheckedBackground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1569624 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonCheckedIndicatorBrush OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1599631 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonPressedForeground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1629634 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonPressedBackground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1669650 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonHoverForeground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1704633 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavButtonHoverBackground OldValue:  NewValue: Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush
06:20:18.1759651 Template10 HamburgerMenu.VisualStateNarrowMinWidth OldValue: -1 NewValue: 0
06:20:18.1799658 Template10 HamburgerMenu.VisualStateNormalMinWidth OldValue: -1 NewValue: 521
06:20:18.1829637 Template10 HamburgerMenu.VisualStateWideMinWidth OldValue: -1 NewValue: 1200
06:20:18.1969625 Template10 HamburgerMenu.NavigationService OldValue:  NewValue: Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService
06:20:18.2154630 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to AfterInit
06:20:18.2254644 Template10 BootStrapper.NavigationServiceFactory backButton:Attach existingContent:Include frame:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame
06:20:18.2279630 Template10 BootStrapper.CreateNavigationService Frame:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame
06:20:18.2344636 Template10 BootStrapper.CallOnStartAsync 
06:20:18.2369622 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to BeforeStart
06:20:18.2419643 Template10 NavigationService.Navigate Page: Decisive.Uwp.T10.Views.MainPage, Parameter: , NavigationTransitionInfo: 
06:20:18.2459663 Template10 NavigationService.NavigateAsync Page: Decisive.Uwp.T10.Views.MainPage, Parameter: , NavigationTransitionInfo: 
06:20:18.2499634 Template10 JsonSerializationService.Serialize Value 
06:20:18.2534646 Template10 FrameFacade.Navigate 
06:20:18.2589630 Template10 FrameFacade.FacadeNavigatingCancelEventHandler 
06:20:18.2619633 Template10 JsonSerializationService.Deserialize Value 
06:20:18.8369651 Template10 FrameFacade.FacadeNavigatedEventHandler 
06:20:18.8389640 Template10 JsonSerializationService.Deserialize Value 
06:20:18.8424652 Template10 JsonSerializationService.Deserialize Value 
06:20:18.8439624 Template10 JsonSerializationService.Serialize Value 
06:20:18.8514648 Template10 HamburgerMenu.HighlightCorrectButton PageType: Decisive.Uwp.T10.Views.MainPage PageParam: 
06:20:18.8589639 Template10 BootStrapper.UpdateShellBackButton 
06:20:18.8629634 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to AfterStart
06:20:18.8649644 Template10 BootStrapper.ActivateWindow source:Launching
06:20:18.8674655 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to Running
06:20:18.8709695 Template10 BootStrapper.CurrentState CurrenstState changed to AfterLaunch
06:20:18.8929626 Template10 NavigationService.NavigateToAsync Mode: New, Parameter:  FrameContent: Decisive.Uwp.T10.Views.MainPage
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
06:20:19.1159643 Template10 HamburgerMenu.HamburgerMenu_Loaded 
06:20:19.1269658 Template10 HamburgerMenu.RefreshStyles Theme: Default
06:20:19.1309641 Template10 HamburgerMenu.RefreshStyles Color: #FF4682B4
06:20:19.1364621 Template10 HamburgerMenu.DisplayMode OldValue: Overlay NewValue: CompactOverlay
06:20:19.1404642 Template10 HamburgerMenu.UpdateControl Manual: , IsFullScreen: False DisplayMode: CompactOverlay
06:20:19.1489629 Template10 HamburgerMenu.UpdateControl Manual: , IsFullScreen: False DisplayMode: CompactOverlay
The program '[58384] Decisive.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: I used Template10 v.1.1.12 to make a simple code sample to test, but I cannot reproduce this issue. Could you please share a [mcve] with us?

Comment: Grab the 1.1.0 vsix, make a project then upgrade it to 1.1.12. That's the problem. I've no problem with 1.1.12 if I start the project with that. The problem lies in upgrading an old 1.1.0 project to 1.1.12. There are considerable changes in code an XAML between these versions.

Comment: Found the debugger setting; Debugger Type->Application process 'Mixed'. Solution->Project->Properties->Debug->Debugger Type.

Comment: So, have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, No, there is no specific upgrade guidance for my older version project v.1.1.0 to current v.1.1.12.

I recall some upgrade comments when Template 10 was very new, I can't find them now.

After chasing down several problems I instead started a new project based on the new templates and moved my code there.